# Why doesnt this code for C to add the digits of a number not work?

Tags: c, numbers

I wrote this simple program to add the digits of a number k. The code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int digitsum(int k)
{
    // This line will find the number of digits in k.
    int size = floor(log(k)/log(10))+1;
    int sum = 0, i, j;
    // Here I find the sum of digits starting with the leading digit.
    for (i=1;i<=size;i++)
    {
        j = floor(k*pow(10,-size+i)); // Leading digit
        sum = sum + j; // Add to sum
        k = k - j*pow(10,size-i); // Delete first digit
        //printf("%d   %d \n", j, k);
    }
    return sum;
}
main()
{
    int k =1141;
    int sum = digitsum(k);
    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

So sometimes my program works, for instance for k=141 it returns 6 but for k=1141 it also returns 6... I realize there is an easier way to do this task by taking the mod 10 and then dividing the number by 10. However I think this code should work. Any ideas what is going wrong? Thanks in advance. Also, I am just starting working with C, if there are any things that are not proper coding or rookie mistakes feel free to let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why so complicated?  Why not keep dividing the number by 10 until it's less than 10 and keep adding the remainder?

Comment: $0xdeadbeef  Yeah I realize this is indeed a much better way to do things and I will use this method. However, I just can't see why this code doesn't work, so I am just curious to see where it's going wrong. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You're probably running into errors like `pow(10, 6)` is `999999.999` which is truncated to `999999`, not `1000000`.

Comment: For k = 1000, I get size = 3. Check that log (which uses the natural log) is what you want. Try the log10() function instead. (This will also simplify the size calcuation.)

Comment: @Jason OP is using the `log base b of a = log(a)/log(b)` identity, so it is correct. However, as you mentioned, `log10` would make it simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I didn't know about the     log10 function!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Mathematically, it is correct. But numerically, it can lead to small differences which make things difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest using `round()` rather than `floor()` when trying to convert `double` to `int`.

```
int size = round(log(k)/log(10)) + 1;
```

When the numeric result is just a tad below a whole number, `floor()` lops off the 0.999999999... fraction.

---

But `round(log(k)/log(10))` as well as `log10(k)` fails when `k` is `0`.  A simple helper function would do:

```
int ilog10(int k) {
  if (k < 0) TBD();  // OP needs to clarify what to do when k < 0
  int sum = 1;
  while (k >= 10) {
    k /= 10;
    sum++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

The solution to the larger problem could well follow @0xdeadbeef comment:

```
int digitsum(int k) {
  if (k < 0) TBD();  // OP needs to clarify what to do when k < 0
  int sum = 0;
  do {
    sum += k%10;
    k /= 10;
  } while (k > 0);
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take care of small rounding errors.
Maybe this would help.

```
j = floor(k*pow(10,-size+i) + 0.000000001);
```